# Топор, топорщится, оттопыривать. Являются ли эти слова родственными?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Если да, тогда какое из них является первичным? В случае, если таковым окажется «топор», интересно было бы узнать о происхождении этого слова. Спасибо.

Comment: Если топор положить в мешок, то мешок будет топорщиться, а если топор положить за пазуху, то рубаха оттопырится (оттопорится?).

Answer (score 3):

Как сказал Фасмер, связь «топора» и «топорщить, топырить» произвольна.

ТОПОР известен на Руси с 11 века как боевое орудие, а в 14 веке  топор (или слово топор) стали использовать плотники.  В др.-рус. языке известно слово тепу – бью, также в диалектах  тёпать – бить, рубить, тяпать. Сравним: тепать – топор, сечь – секира. Слово общеславянское, а корень tip/top  –  звукоподражательный, как и в слове «топать».

ТОПЫРИТЬ и ТОПОРЩИТЬ связывают с глаголом «пырить», в диалектах он встречается со значением «ощетиниваться». Также известен глагол «пырять», экспрессивная форма от «пороть», а там и до греков недалеко:  piero (греч.) – колю, режу.

Comment: Осталось совсем немного этимологам : объяснить префикс (?) **то-** в глаголе *топырить*. Есть ли еще подобные примеры с подобным морфом.  
То/пырить, от/то/пырить...  
Вопрос интересный.

Comment: Может быть, влияние  "торчать". Это общеславянское слово, буквально  - "выдаваться, колоть", например (s)tark (польск) - колючка.Также есть диалектное "торкать" - толкать.

Comment: то- выравнивать, подравнивать. Пороть и пырять слова разные.

Comment: Пороть - разрезать по швам, пырять - вонзать что-то острое, оба слова происходят от piero (греч.) – колю, режу.